# How do I ignore all `misc.xml` files but only if they're inside a folder named `.idea` in Subversion?

Tags: svn

I would like to instruct Subversion to ignore the files `.idea/misc.xml` and `.idea/workspace.xml`. I have several of these `.idea` folders at multiple levels below the repo root, and I was wondering how/if I could tell Subversion to ignore them anywhere below the current directory? Something like `**/.idea/misc.xml`...

Comment: Maybe with a server side pre-commit hook script? Or some client side hook-script (but they depend on svn client)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify multiple-level paths in svn's ignore definitions. So unless you can ignore all xml files everywhere, or unless you can ignore the entire .idea directory, this cannot be done. You will need to specify ignore definitions on *every* .idea directory.